# Unable to resolve “expo-app-loading” from “App.js”

Tags: android, error-handling, expo, react-native

I am getting this error:

> Failed building JavaScript bundle. Unable to resolve
> “expo-app-loading” from “App.js”

when I ran my project after a couple of months. Earlier it was working fine but not now.
Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please add some code snippet to reproduce the error. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] Please read this.

Comment: Please post your package.json too and the part where you use App Loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems:

1. `expo-app-loading` was not in my package.json, so I just installed it again and boom, it was in my packege.json then.
2. I was importing 'AppLoading' the wrong way. I wrote

   ```
    import {AppLoading} from "expo-app-loading";  //wrong way
   ```

   Which was breaking. Then I corrected it to

   ```
    import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";    //correct way
   ```

   Which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you recently updated SDK versions (expo upgrade), please be sure to review the breaking  changes carefully as is advised when you complete the install.

For instance, SDK-40 which was released in December has breaking changes notes about expo-app-loading that probably addresses what you're seeing perfectly.

Read this page : https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-40-is-now-available-d4d73e67da33

Look for section title: AppLoading has been extracted from the expo package